# Facebook PHP SDK getUser() returns nothing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK to register new users with data pulled from the Facebook API.

When I visit the page with the code below, the `echo $uid` returns nothing. Not `0`. Not `null`. Just nothing.

The simplified code looks like this:

```
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = $appid;
$config['secret'] = $appsecret;
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$uid = $facebook->getUser();

$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
  'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.website.com',
  'display' => 'page', //could be popup
  'cookie' => true,
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

echo 'uid = '.$uid;

    if($uid) {
        //SHOW SOMETHIN'
        echo 'AUTHORIZED!';

        //CREATE NEW USER...
        //SIGN IN NEWLY CREATED USER...

    } else {
        //PROMPT TO AUTHORIZE
        echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">SIGN IN WITH FACEBOOK.</a>';

    };
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post some more code ? This looks perfect to me

Comment: @Jashwant: I added some more code so you can see the context. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_permalink($post->ID)` should be the culprit.

Is it the same you specified as `Site URL` in app settings ?

(My little wp knowledge says, this url is going to be dynamic)

*For security reasons, facebook redirect to `Site URL` only and not just any url.*

Comment: AHA. That seems promising. I changed it but it I'm still not getting the expected results. I'm going to update the question momentarily, but it looks like I'm getting nothing when I echo `$uid`. Not `0` but nothing. Very strange.

Comment: Now, can you show the updated code and `Site URL` in app settings ?

Comment: I hard-coded the correct url (and updated the code above). I checked the app settings in FB and it's the same url. I see the echo statement before the if, but it reders as `UID = `. No 0.

Comment: var_dump `$loginUrl`  and var_dump `$uid`

Comment: It works for me . I was redirected to http://www.your_site.com/member-profile/. I guess, you should try with another facebook user or revoke permissions from the your app and start again :) You may delete the above comment.

Comment: That part works for me too, which is why I'm very confused why $uid is never defined. Shouldn't this be at least `0`? I think we've zeroed in on the root of this problem: Why is $uid null if everything else seems to be working?

Comment: As far as I know, it contains `null` not `0` until you grant permission.

Comment: Ooooooooo. The documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/) says it should return `0`, but maybe it's wrong.

Here's a var_dump of the $facebook object. Would mind taking a look?
`object(Facebook)#277 (8) { ["appId:protected"]=> string(15) "316629258405322" ["apiSecret:protected"]=> string(32) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ["session:protected"]=> NULL ["signedRequest:protected"]=> NULL ["sessionLoaded:protected"]=> bool(true) ["cookieSupport:protected"]=> bool(false) ["baseDomain:protected"]=> string(0) "" ["fileUploadSupport:protected"]=> bool(false) }`

Comment: But actually, now that I think about it, shouldn't it be defined once the current FB user has authorized the app? So even if it's 0/null the first time, each subsequent visit should $uid should be defined, right?

Comment: Right, it should work when facebook redirects user to the `site url`.

Comment: New clue: if I move `$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');` out of the conditional, I get an error: `Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /home/useracct/public_html/wp-content/plugins/facebook-php-sdk/facebook.php on line 461`

Something tells me this is important. What do you think?

Comment: You are not getting `the access_token`. Are you sure, you are using the latest fb sdk. They have changed the parameters when they redirect to your page.

Use this one, https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Comment: AHA! I've been referencing the facebook.php from a plugin. I just checked it and it's version 2.1.2, which I think is old. I'm going to try the newer version right now and report back...

Comment: I swapped the facebook.php for a newer version. Now $uid is = 0. This is progress!

Comment: This question got a bit confusing because there are clearly were a couple things going on. I think we solved the immediate issue, so I'm going to mark this as solved and start a new question that addresses the persistent `0` issue specifically.